# Import module only if iOS 11 is available

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want to import a module from CocoaPods in my project which has the minimum deployment target set to iOS 9.0.

In my Podfile, I set the minimum deployment target for that specific framework to iOS 11 like this:

```
  #CoreML
  platform :ios, '11.0'
  pod 'xxx', '1.0.0'
```

so that it would allow me to `pod install`.

The problem is when I import it in my file, I receive the following error:

> Module file's minimum deployment target is ios11.0 v11.0.

How should I import it only if iOS 11 is available? I tried using

```
if #available(iOS 11, *) { ... }
```

and `@available(iOS 11)`, but with no luck.

Comment: Hi Toma, any updates on this issue?

Comment: Did you find any solutions for it? I have the same issue. My project has minimum deployment target at ios8, and all the other codes are supports it by using @available or #available or #if canImport to work around version, arch constraints. However this minimum deployment target has no way to work around as for as I am searching. I feel a bit crazy to lift the minimum requirement from 8 to 10 just because of one framework. Did you find any way to do it? The last choice I would try might be to pull the source code from github and modify it..

Comment: @Surely I can’t remember exactly but I think thatthe I downloaded the problematic library from GitHub, removed it from Cocoapods and imported it in my project.

Comment: @TomaRadu-Petrescu thanks, I think I should go that way as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Podfiles don‘t support Pod-specific deployment targets. You can set a deployment target for all Pods and the resulting aggregate target like you did with `platform :ios, 'x.y'`
2. You could set a Pod-specific deployment target in the Podspec of your Lib: `spec.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'` -> But that wouldn’t help in your case.
3. It makes no sense to use a higher deployment target in your Podfile (11.0) than in your Project (9.0). These values should always be equal.

**Solution**: set `platform :ios, '9.0'` in your Podfile and conditionally import / use your 11.0-only Lib with @available and #available. You may also need to **optionally link** your lib under "Link with Libraries", see [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002378-BBCJICEC)

If this doesn’t work for you, please share more information (full Podfile, Xcode & Cocoapods Version, Podspec of the Lib)